# auto loading class in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I use this bundle: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle 
and get all way explained in the that site but i occured with this error

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "JMSI18nRoutingBundle" from namespace "JMS\I18nRoutingBundle" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 20. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

my configuration is this:
in app/autoload.php i wrote this for add namespace alias:

```
$loader->add('JMS', __DIR__ .'/../vendor/bundles');
```

and in app/AppKernel.php i register bundle, in this section error occured when i register bundle.

```
new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
```

I copy this library into vendor/budles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: which symfony version are you using?

Comment: Maybe the bundle is not installed properly; check **Symfony\vendors\composer\autoload_namespaces.php** and make sure your bundle name exists there. If that did not work re-install the bundle through the composer and use `--prefer-dist` switch

Comment: @Wouter J: Symfony 2.4.3

Comment: @ArazJafaripur then you should use composer to install the bundle and not care about configuring the autoloader at all (because composer already takes care of that)

Answer (score 0):

See - https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/composer.json

As you can see, there defined full-path namespace

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "JMS\\I18nRoutingBundle": "" }
    },
```

Try to define

```
$loader->add('JMS\\I18nRoutingBundle', __DIR__ .'/../vendor/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle');
```

And best way - use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: wasn't work this, i doesn't load with composer, i just copied Bundle into vendor/bundles